# Check if a link has been opened in another window [JS or jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple jQuery script that launches modal to report the page is loading (*working properly*) because there are times when script processing takes some time.

My problem comes when the user clicks on the link that launches a modal in new window (*either with the middle mouse button or via the contextual menu*).

Then, the modal displays and the page loads in a new tab but in the parent the modal is visible (*when it should not because the content is already loaded in another tab*).

Is it possible to launch the modal only when the request is made for the same tab, not a new one?

Here is the jQuery code and a demo:

```
// Loading Modal
$(' #launch ').click(function(){
    $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e914a1jv/

Thank you very much to all.

**Solution**:

Here is the resulting jQuery code:

```
// Loading Modal
$(' #launch ').mousedown(function(evt) {
    if(evt.which == 1) 
    {
        if ( evt.ctrlKey === false )
        {
            $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You could check whether the click on #launch is a left click and only launch the modal if the user left clicks it.

Comment: If you're going to do that you also need to check for the CTRL or Command key being held down too.

Comment: Thanks @Siva. The result jQuery code is at the bottom of answer :)

Comment: Thanks @rory-mccrossan. The result jQuery code is at the bottom of answer :)

Comment: You should add that code as an answer, so that this question can be marked answered.

Comment: @Rouby Done! Sorry :)

Comment: No need to apologize (remember to accept it, I think you have to wait a day?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION

Here is the resulting jQuery code:

```
// Loading Modal
$(' #launch ').mousedown(function(evt) {
    if(evt.which == 1) 
    {
        if ( evt.ctrlKey === false )
        {
            $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
        }
    }
});
```